# Unable to send data from node red to thingspeak

Tags: matlab, node-red

As the titel stats i am unable to send data from node red to thingspeak.
The input is in a json file.The data is first passed to a fuction node then a thingspeak42 node.
The input sets payload as `"rpm": 1000, "water": 50, "temp": 25, "humidity": 60`.

Fuction code

```
// Set the Thingspeak channel ID and API write key
var channelId = "****";
var apiKey = "******";

// Set the property names that correspond to the "rpm", "water", "temp", and "humidity" fields in the payload
var fieldProps = ["rpm", "water", "temp", "humidity"];

// Create the Thingspeak API URL with the channel ID and API write key
var apiUrl = "https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=" + apiKey + "&";

// Build the API URL with the field values
var values = [];
fieldProps.forEach(function (prop) {
    values.push(prop + "=" + msg.payload[prop]);
});
var apiQuery = apiUrl + values.join("&");

// Store the API query in the message payload
msg.topic = apiQuery;
return msg;
```

I have already checked if the channelId and the apiKey there is no error there.Also have tried changing the topic in the thingspeak42 node to the same name on thingspeak and 1,2,3,4.

Comment: You are manually building the URL, fixing this will solve the problem

Comment: can I have an example?